# Redirect URI Mismatch Error from Google Plus sign in

Tags: uri, google-oauth, google-signin, google-plus-signin

While attempting to implement Google+ sign in, I receive this error:

[image: error page]

Upon clicking the sign in button, I receive a `redirect_uri_mismatch`,  error stating that:

```
The JavaScript origin in the request: 
http://70132bd6.ngrok.com did not match a registered JavaScript origin.
```

I have added the link (along with several others just in case) in my developer console under origins:

[image: google developers console]

How do I resolve this mismatch issue?

Additionally, why is there a prepended `storagerelay://` in the redirect uri of the request details. It says it is: `redirect_uri=storagerelay://http/70132bd6.ngrok.com?id=auth109348`. Where is the extra part coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are using correct client_id. It is common that developers created multiple clients, and set those origins on a different client. Please double check.